# I can't make a mouseover/mouseout JQuery div transition on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, mouseover, tumblr

This is my first time using any form of JavaScript and after hours of painstakingly toying with this code, I'm at a loss. I can't be the only one.

I'm trying to create a transition effect that starts with a div containing the text "HOVER". When moused over, it expands another text-related div while hiding the "HOVER" div. When the mouse is removed, the "HOVER" div will return.

While I do think I've figured out the code and it works on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLk6G/5/) (only as JQuery OnLoad), it won't work on Tumblr. I'm able to get the hover expanding animation, but the second text div will not replace the "HOVER" div. The "HOVER" div is always visible.

I've tried changing the src links for Tumblr to recognize and load JQuery, I've tried placing a trigger extension on the body tag (may have done this incorrectly though), and I've tried to paste the codes in the header, after the starting body tag and before the closing body tag.

The script in my header:

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://static.tumblr.com/53unaru/kx3lgzker/jquery-1.3.2.min.js” charset=”utf-8”></script>

<script>
    $('#descriptiontext1').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('#descriptiontext2').show();
    $('#descriptiontext1').hide();
        });
});

$('#descriptiontext2'').on('mouseout', function () {
    $('#descriptiontext1').show();
    $('#descriptiontext2').hide();
        });
});
</script>
```

The CSS:

```
#description2 {
    z-index: 999;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:justify;
    left:0px;
    top:436px;
    margin-left:70px;
    width: 150px;
    height:15px;
    padding:1px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    font-family:'brie';
    font-size:10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow-y:none;
    overflow-x:none;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#description2:hover {
    z-index: 999;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:355px;
    margin-left:20px;
    width: 232px;
    height:150px;
    padding:15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#descriptiontext1 {
    padding:0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'brie';
    font-size:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#descriptiontext2 {
    padding:15px;
    font-family:'brie';
    font-size:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    display: none;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="description2">
<div id="descriptiontext1">HOVER</div>
<div id="descriptiontext2">TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN TESTIN</div></div>
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the tumblelog displaying the issue. Make sure your jQuery code is after your markup. I would also query why you are including two versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$('#descriptiontext1').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('#descriptiontext2').show();
    $('#descriptiontext1').hide();
        });
});

$('#descriptiontext2'').on('mouseout', function () {
    $('#descriptiontext1').show();
    $('#descriptiontext2').hide();
        });
});
```

To

```
$.noConflict();
    $(function () {
        $('#descriptiontext1').on('mouseover', function () {
            $('#descriptiontext2').show();
            $('#descriptiontext1').hide();
        });

        $('#descriptiontext2').on('mouseout', function () {
            $('#descriptiontext1').show();
            $('#descriptiontext2').hide();
        });
    });
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsbin.com/dejeb/1/edit)**

use `$.noConflict();` method because you are using two versions of `jquery` library.
you can see the full documentation [**here**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this gave me the same result that I was already receiving. ):

Comment: Tried your edit with and without the second version of jquery library. I'm not sure why is wrong with Tumblr. It works on it's own outside of Tumblr, but not inside Tumblr's coding.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your event bindings inside a DOM ready event. This is pretty common in jQuery and essential to counter loading issues.

```
// once the DOM is ready
$(function(){
    $('#descriptiontext1').on('mouseover', function () {
        $('#descriptiontext2').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $('#descriptiontext2').on('mouseout', function () {
        $('#descriptiontext1').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Also note jQuery supports a toggle function which handles/toggles `show()` and `hide()` automatically. Haven't tested it but something along the lines of this might work for you if `descriptiontext2` is hidden by default:

```
$(function(){
    var descriptions = $('#descriptiontext1, #descriptiontext2');

    descriptions.on('mouseover, mouseout', function () {
        descriptions.toggle();
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/u9QNc/)**

Comment: Forgive me for being completely new to this, but would you be able to explain or offer a clear guide to how to wrap my event bindings inside a DOM? I tried to mess around with what I could find on it, but I'm 100% sure I'm doing this wrong. I tried the latter as well with the same results. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your problem starts when the page loads, it takes the `head` first, loads the jQuery library (+-100ms). It continues to bind your events, looking for `$('#descriptiontext1')` and 2 (+-200ms) but those objects will be empty. Only then the HTML is loaded (+-300ms). Using the DOM ready handler your event binding is on hold, until your HTML is loaded. Only then you can be sure the objects are found.

Comment: See a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/u9QNc/). Also note in CSS and jQuery selectors, the `#` is for the `id` attribute. `.` is for the `class` attribute. Both options seem to work as anticipated. Not sure why you include 2 versions of jQuery. Try to go for 1.11.0 instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, I tried that and I'm still getting the exact same result. Also tried with a copy of 1.11.0 and without the second jquery version. I'm not sure why is wrong with Tumblr. It works on it's own outside of Tumblr, but not inside Tumblr's coding.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way, if you want to make it advance, you can use on event listener for both mouseout, mouse in and functions for better readability and optimization. Also you don't have to use js to hide and show, you can use css3 as well.

```
$('#descriptiontext1').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('#descriptiontext2, #descriptiontext1').toggle();
});

$('#descriptiontext2').on('mouseout', function () {
    $('#descriptiontext2, #descriptiontext1').toggle();
});
```

Comment: This provided me the same results that I was getting before. I tried using just CSS to perform what I wanted, but it wouldn't replace the first div with the second, it would just extend the second below it. Along with that, it wouldn't hide the second div. It would appear below the first one. That's the reason I began delving into this unfortunately. What a mess. ):